# implementing a switch type trait (with std::conditional_t chain calls)

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

this is what i want, a "switch" type trait that returns the first type which has a condition == true:

```
ext::select_t<condition1 == true, Type1,
              condition2 == true, type2,
              condition3 == true, type3>
```

etc, and be able to add as many condition / type pairs as i want.

i can do this with std::conditional as such (random example):

```
template<typename Number,
         typename Distribution = std::conditional_t<
                 // IF
                 std::is_integral<Number>::value,
                 // RETURN INT
                 std::uniform_int_distribution<Number>,
                 // ELSE
                 std::conditional_t<std::is_floating_point<Number>::value,
                                    // RETURN REAL
                                   std::uniform_real_distribution<Number>, void>>>

Number random(Number min, Number max)
{
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 mt(rd());

    Distribution dist(min, max);

    return dist(mt);
}
```

as you can see it decides at compile time what kind of distribution i want depending on the conditions/types passed.

obviously this can get real ugly real fast if i try to add more conditions, imagine i want 10 of them.

so i tried to build one, but failed miserably:

```
template<bool B, typename T>
struct cond
{
    static constexpr bool value = B;
    using type = T;
};

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct select
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<Head::value, typename Head::type, select<Tail...>>;
};

template<typename Head>
struct select<Head>
{
    using type = std::conditional_t<Head::value, typename Head::type, void>;
};

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
using select_t = typename select<Head, Tail...>::type;
```

the reason i tried to make a cond structure is so i can get "pairs" of conditions/types, so i can get any number of those using variadic templates, but this makes it even more uglier (and not working):

```
using Type = std::select_t<cond<false, void>,
                           cond<false, int>,
                           cond<true, std::string>>;
```

not only it doesn't look as good as i want the final version to be, but it doesn't even work! it only works when the first condition is true..

is there anything im missing? also how could i achieve this in a more clean way (at least for the end user).

thanks in advance.

Comment: What if none of the conditions is true?

Comment: if none are true it just returns void. obviously the optimal solution would be to just fail to compile if theres no true condition. depending in what the end user does, void will (almost) always make the compilation fail, but it could somehow compile fine and make a bug in the code, dont know really how to solve that problem too..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in your base case:

```
using type = std::conditional_t<Head::value, typename Head::type, select<Tail...>>;
```

You want on success (`Head::value`) to use the head type (`Head::type`), but on failure to use the tail type. But `select<Tail...>` isn't the tail type. That's a metafunction. You want to actually evaluate it:

```
using type = std::conditional_t<
                 Head::value, 
                 typename Head::type,
                 typename select<Tail...>::type>;
```

Now this is a little inefficient, since you have to process the entirety of the conditional up top. For that, you could write a separate metafunction which Boost.MPL had called `eval_if`. Instead of taking a boolean and two types, it takes a boolean and two metafunctions:

```
template <bool B, typename TrueF, typename FalseF>
struct eval_if {
    using type = typename TrueF::type;
};

template <typename TrueF, typename FalseF>
struct eval_if<false, TrueF, FalseF> {
    using type = typename FalseF::type;
};    

template <bool B, typename T, typename F>
using eval_if_t = typename eval_if<B, T, F>::type;
```

With which your main case for `select` becomes:

```
template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct select
{
    using type = eval_if_t<Head::value,
                           Head,
                           select<Tail...>>;
};
```

Although on reflection, the same could be accomplished with `std::conditional_t` and inheritance:

```
template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct select
: std::conditional_t<Head::value, Head, select<Tail...>>
{ };
```

---

Also, typically we would just have an "else" case at the end, so maybe you'd write your selector as:

```
using T = select_t<cond<C1, int>,
                   cond<C2, float>,
                   double>;
```

So I would suggest writing your base case thusly:

```
template <typename T>
struct select<T>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <bool B, typename T>
struct select<cond<B, T>>
{
    // last one had better be true!
    static_assert(B, "!");
    using type = T;
};
```

Also, you wrote `std::select_t`... don't put this in namespace `std`, put it in your own namespace.

Comment: another comment: the "else" return is a good idea too, i can even make it return a default one. but final question: there’s no way i can do this without a cond<bool, T> struct that hold a pair right? even using like 2 variadic template arguments? i tried that too but couldn’t make it work. anyway thanks a lot again.

Comment: @sap With multiple template arguments, they would all have to be types. You'd have to pass something like `std::true_type` instead of `true`. Otherwise, the implementation is the same - just peel off two arguments from the pack at a time instead of one.

Comment: thanks @Barry ill try that later as an exercise, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: An other alternative is `template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct select
{
    using type = typename std::conditional_t<Head::value, Head, select<Tail...>>::type;
}` (yes `_t<..>::type` :-) ).